# Using mouse position to control character animation

Tags: unreal-engine4, unrealscript

I would like to set up an animation for my character and have the progression through the animation be controlled by the mouse movement.

E.g. the character starts in a rest state - the first frame of the animation - as the mouse moves through the x axis, it plays the animation forward in a linear relationship with the movement of the mouse. If you stop, the animation halts at that point and if you move backwards, the animation is reversed.
Like scrubbing in a video editor except instead of a vide, it's a character animation.

I'm guessing this is eminently doable but will it be relatively trivial to do within Blueprints or am I better off using C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SquidInker!

I'm two years late here, but for the sake of Google posterity here is the Blueprint solution as of engine 4.17.0:

In your Animation Blueprint, right-click on the node for the animation asset in question, and [select "convert to single frame animation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfGIJ.png)

Your node will now have [an "explicit time" input pin,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o27Nx.png) which you can parameterize as you like to scrub through your animation: